# Python list.remove() removes items from another list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to remove the folders containing 'Done' in the folder name. Here is my code

```
import os
mainPath = os.getcwd() + "/MyFolder/"
folderList = os.listdir(mainPath)
tempList = folderList     # so that I can iterate while using remove()
print len(tempList)
print len(folderList)
for folder in tempList:
    if 'Done' in folder:
        folderList.remove(folder)
print len(tempList)       # expected: Not to change
print len(folderList)
```

The output I get is:
26
26
22
22

I do not understand why it is deleting items from *testList*. Shouldn't it delete only from *folderList*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the lists point to the same thing. use `copy.deepcopy`

Essentially when you do `tempList = folderList` it makes the two lists point to the same thing. If you want two copies of the same list that you can operate on separately you need to do:

```
import copy

tempList = copy.deepcopy(folderList)
```

If you know that all the items in your list are immutable, you can do `tempList = folderList[:]`, but `deepcopy` is safer.

There's a wealth of information on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)